# Entity FrameWork, LINQ StartsWith() not working on Collection?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I am having an issue with LINQ and `StartWith()` applied to a collection.

This is the a simplified version of the query on the `DataBase`, this returns the correct records:

```
using (Entities entities = new Entities())
{               
     var result = entities.StaffData.Where(p => 
                       p.Staff_Name_First.StartsWith(myString)
                       p.Is_Alive == true);                
}
```

As stated above, this returns the correct records,

However when placed on a collection that holds the all the records with the criteria `Is_Alive == true`. This collection hold approximately 500 records.

```
public static ObservableCollection<StaffData> MyCollection = new ObservableCollection<StaffData>();

var result = MyCollection.Where(p => 
                       p.Staff_Name_First.StartsWith(myString)
                       p.Is_Alive == true);
```

So when applying the query to the collection I get message in the results :

> Message = "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

I tried to find out what this means in this context, but I can't seem to work it out. Why would this be happening?

Comment: You sure none of your `p.Staff_Name_First` is _null_? Definitely one of your 500 records is null and thus the error!

Comment: `Staff_Name_First` is null for some items in `MyCollection`. When you make EF query that is different, because it just converts your Where into sql query, and sql just skips items where Staff_Name_First is not present.

Comment: @RahulSingh, are you asking if there is a single record that has a null value in `p.Staff_Name_First`, if so, yes there is a possibility that some values will be null.

Comment: Well and why wouldn't that cause error? Suppose you have `StaffData x = new StaffData(); x.Staff_Name_First.StartsWith(myString)`< will throw NullReference exception. Same story in your case. How to fix: check for null.

Comment: @Evk, thanks for the help, I see what I was doing wrong. Cheers

Comment: Looking back on this I am so embarrassed by this question. What  simple problem, that is so easily fixed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that some of your `Staff_Name_First` properties are null. EF ignores the null reference when you do `p.Staff_Name_First.StartsWith` with your entities since they are converted to SQL.

But when you convert it to an in-memory collection with `ObservableCollection<StaffData> MyCollection`, `p.Staff_Name_First.StartsWith` throws an exception.

Check for nulls when querying `MyCollection`:

```
var result = MyCollection.Where(p => 
                       p.Staff_Name_First != null && 
                       p.Staff_Name_First.StartsWith(myString) &&
                       p.Is_Alive);
```

Comment: Well what do you know, I learnt something again today, but not what you would expect. I was checking for null values, but after the `StartsWith()` clause, that kept giving me an error, once I moved the check for null before the `StartsWith()` in the query, no more error. Thanks for the help. Have to wait a few more minutes before I can accept.

Comment: @KyloRen - Or if you are using C# 6 you can shorten it to : `MyCollection.Where(p => p.Staff_Name_First?.StartsWith(myString) ?? false && p.Is_Alive)`

Comment: Definitely get rid of the `== true`; equality comparison returns a bool and Is_Alive is already a bool.

Comment: @RahulSingh, thanks again for the help. I am going to go look for one of your helpful answers now and upvote!!